# Can't see PDF Reports in Accounting -Odoo 11 EE

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I logged in as an administrator with Adviser access rights. But the user can't see the menu item for PDF reports under Reporting Menu.[image]

Do I need to change any other settings?
How can resolve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upgrade the module `account`. Then it will appear.
After the upgrade the menu `PDF Report` has shown in Settings -> Technical -> User interface -> menuitems. Before it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ever modified permissions through menu "Users & Companies" - "Groups", you could have accidentally removed someone's inherited permission.

To see the "PDF Reports" menu, the user needs to have "Accounting & Finance / Accountant"; "Advisor" users should be in such group automatically unless later removed.

Please enable the developer mode, go to "Users & Companies" - "Groups", search for "Accountant", then open "Accounting & Finance / Accountant" and make sure the related admin user is inside under the "Users" tab.